# How to get count of records in a table?

Tags: vb.net

Someone help me
I am working on our project and I need to check if my DB has already 20 records.
If so, then it will not accept records anymore.
I've been trying the codes below:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim ds, ds2 As New DataSet
Dim da, da2 As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql, sql1 As String
Dim int As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source = |datadirectory|\Database6.mdb"
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
    Dim sdr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim cmd1 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Accounts")
    sql = "INSERT INTO Accounts ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "') "
    sql1 = "SELECT Count([AccountID]) FROM Accounts"

    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd1 = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql1, con)
    Convert.ToInt32(sql1)
    cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
    If sql1 < 20 Then
        MsgBox("Cannot accept records")
    ElseIf sdr.HasRows = False Then
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Account Added")
    ElseIf sdr.HasRows = True Then
        MsgBox("Username is taken")
    End If


    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

But the convert code fires an error :

> Input string was in incorrect format

But if I delete the convert code it gives me the error

> Conversion from string "SELECT Count([AccountID]) FROM A" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Help me please.
TIA

Comment: Try  typing this in your textbox: `';drop Database6;` /kidding, dont do that! But I would highly suggest reading about SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injectionattacks.

Comment: Yes. I know all about SQL Injection. But it's not the focus of our project. We just need to show that the DB cannot accept anymore records after the 20th record has been added. Can you help me please?

Comment: First piece of help - this is not VBA. If you tag your question correctly your chances will improve.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME`???

Comment: It gives me an error when I use SELECT COUNT(*).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know VB all that well, this is from the top of my head. Your trying to convert your SQL text, which will never work. Try something like this:

```
dim result as object
result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()
dim count as int
count = Convert.ToInt32(result)
If count < 20 Then
```

Comment: @Bampie: If the above answer was helpful, please don't forget to accept/upvote.